# Mongodb geospatial query with time field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a lot of different documents each containing a "savetime" field along with a point. Is it possible to query not only for all documents containing a location $near a point, but also within that same time (or within 1 second of each other)? What is the best way to perform the query to ensure maximal performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/):

> A [compound](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#index-type-compound) 2dsphere index can reference multiple location and non-location fields within a collection’s documents. You can arrange the fields in any order.

So in order for you to perform your queries that are *constrained* by a time, then you would create a [compound](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#index-type-compound) index that has the "savetime" as it's **first** element. i.e:

```js
db.collection.ensureIndex({ savetime: 1, loc: "2dsphere" })
```

That allows you to constrain dates normally while adding your additional constraints for finding near that point:

```js
db.collection.find({ 
    savetime: { $gte: new Date(<start>), $lte: new Date(<end>) },
    loc: { $near :
             { $geometry :
                 { type : "Point" ,
                   coordinates : [ <longitude> , <latitude> ] } ,
                   $maxDistance : <distance in meters>
                 }
             }
         }
})
```

For more information see the tutorials on [creating](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-a-2dsphere-index/) and [querying](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-a-2dsphere-index/).